# Why is there so much of a speed difference in these factorial functions?

Tags: recursion, python-2.7, factorial, divide-and-conquer

So I recently became interested in computing factorials really fast, and I wrote one and and got a few others from the internet to test. Here is the code (Python 2.7):

```
def prime_sieve(n):
    """A prime sieve, takes an int n, and returns all the primes < n"""
    odds = range(3,n+1,2) #make a list of odd numbers starting at 3
    i = 0 #an index counter
    sqrt_n = int(n**0.5) #upper limit for sieving is isqrt(n)
    d = len(odds) #the length of the list
    while odds[i]<=sqrt_n:
        if odds[i]: #odds[i]!=0
            step = odds[i] #the ith odd which is nonzero is the next prime
            start = (i+1)*step + i #this is the location of odds[i]^2
            while start<d: #zero out stepth odd from start.
                odds[start]=0
                start+=step
        i+=1
    return [2]+filter(None, odds) #return a list of primes

#This one I wrote, and the stuff above
def factorial(n):
    """A factorial function which computes n! using it's prime factors"""
    factors = [[i, 0] for i in prime_sieve(n)] #a list holding factor-exp pairs
    for i in xrange(len(factors)): #find the exponents
        m=float(n)
        while factors[i][0]<m:
            m/=factors[i][0]
            factors[i][1]+=int(m)
    result = 1 << factors[0][1] #start off by shifting result, instead of x 2^m
    for i in factors[1:]: #multiply result by every prime factor^exp
        result*=i[0]**i[1]
    return result

#the next two are the obvious ones
def naive_factorial(n):
    """Calculates n! with a simple while loop"""
    result = n
    while (n-1)>1: #n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)...*2*1
        result*=(n-1)
        n-=1
    return result

def recursive_fact(n):
    """Calculates n! recursively"""
    if n<=1: return 1 #n! = n*(n-1)!
    return n*recursive_fact(n-1)

def factorial2(n):
    """Another factorial claiming to be fast, pulled from the internet
       I have no idea how this works"""
    result = 1
    buf = 1
    power2 = 0
    stack = []

    while n > 1:
        stack.append(n)
        n /= 2
        power2 += n

    for n1 in stack[::-1]:
        while n <= n1:
            buf *= n 
            n += 2
        result *= buf

    result <<= power2
    return result

def multiply_range(n, m):
    if n == m:
        return n
    if m < n:
        return 1
    else:
        return multiply_range(n, (n+m)/2) * multiply_range((n+m)/2+1, m)

def factorial3(n):
    """"Also from the internet, the logic seems reasonable, 'divide and conquer'. """
    return multiply_range(1, n)


if __name__=="__main__":
    import math
    import cProfile
    print "Calculating 70000! using naive_factorial."
    cProfile.run("naive_factorial(70000)")
    print "\nCalculating 70000! using math.factorial."
    cProfile.run("math.factorial(70000)")
    print "\nCalculating 70000! using factorial."
    cProfile.run("factorial(70000)")
    print "\nCalculating 70000! using factorial2."
    cProfile.run("factorial2(70000)")
    print "\nCalculating 70000! using factorial3."
    cProfile.run("factorial3(70000)")
```

I'm not new to python, i have been using it for a couple years as my main language, but the results were a bit unexpected...

```
Calculating 70000! using naive_factorial.
         3 function calls in 19.842 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   19.842   19.842 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   19.842   19.842   19.842   19.842 factorial.py:30(naive_factorial)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



Calculating 70000! using math.factorial.
         3 function calls in 22.372 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   22.372   22.372 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   22.372   22.372   22.372   22.372 {math.factorial}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



Calculating 70000! using factorial.
         8 function calls in 9.092 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.003    0.003    9.092    9.092 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.020    0.020    0.024    0.024 factorial.py:1(prime_sieve)
        1    9.066    9.066    9.090    9.090 factorial.py:17(factorial)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 {filter}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.002    0.002    0.002    0.002 {range}



Calculating 70000! using factorial2.
         19 function calls in 5.791 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.791    5.791 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    5.791    5.791    5.791    5.791 factorial.py:43(factorial2)
       16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



Calculating 70000! using factorial3.
         140002 function calls (4 primitive calls) in 1.147 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.147    1.147 <string>:1(<module>)
 139999/1    1.147    0.000    1.147    1.147 factorial.py:65(multiply_range)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.147    1.147 factorial.py:73(factorial3)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

My question is, How can that last one be Soo much faster?! Look at all the recursion! I thought that Python doesn't like recursion! So why is it so much faster? How does factorial2 work? Also, just so everyone knows, I checked that these are all producing the correct outputs for a few different values, so I am pretty sure these all work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to "how does `factorial2()` work: It sort of picks out all the odd numbers while just *counting* how many times the result will have to be multiplied by 2 (the variable `power2`, multiplies only the odd numbers with each other, and in a last step shifts the binary representation of the result left (in effect, multiplying it by `2**power2`).

As to "why so much faster", I'm not clear on whether you're interpreting your results right: The figure of `140002 function calls` appears to include calls of `multiply_range()`. It's still fast (I'm getting 1.6s vs. 4.4s with `factorial2` on 5 runs with `n=70000`), but not outrageaously so.